# How to handle routes after login with react Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, auth0

I have 3 roles in my app and this is the way I am redirecting to the homepage after authentication.

First I check if my user is authenticated using Auth0 SDK:

```js
function App() {
  const { user, isAuthenticated, getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      
      {isAuthenticated ? 
        (
            <Profile />
        )
        :
        <> 
          <h1>HomePage</h1>
          <Login />
        </>
      }

      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

if user is authenticated I then use < Profile />. Here I choose the page where it is redirected based on the role the user has

```js
//imports here

const Profile = () => {
  const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
  const [userType, setUserType] = useState("")


  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const token = await getAccessTokenSilently();      
        var decoded = jwt_decode(token);      
        setUserType(decoded["http://myApp.com/role"])        
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    })();
  }, []);
    

  return(

    <Router>      
        {userType === "Admin" && <> <Redirect to= "/Admin" /></>}
        {userType === "Anfitrion" && <Redirect to= "/Anfitrion" /> }   
        {userType === "Inspector" && <Redirect to="/Inspector" /> }

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/Admin">
            <Admin />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/Anfitrion">
            <Anfitrion />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/Inspector">
            <Inspector />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
  
};

export default Profile;
```

Now that the user is authenticated and redireted to his/her Dashboard page I have  this(for instance: if the user is === "Anfitrion"):

```js
//imports here


export default function DashboardAnfitrion() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);
  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };
  const fixedHeightPaper = clsx(classes.paper, classes.fixedHeight);

  return (
    //---------------This is the static part
    <Router >
    <ThemeProvider theme={Theme}>
    <div className={classes.root}>      
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar position="absolute" className={clsx(classes.appBar, open && classes.appBarShift)}>
        <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
          <IconButton
            edge="start"
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            onClick={handleDrawerOpen}
            className={clsx(classes.menuButton, open && classes.menuButtonHidden)}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography component="h1" variant="h6" color="inherit" noWrap className={classes.title}>
            Dashboard
          </Typography>
          <IconButton color="inherit">
            <Badge badgeContent={4} color="secondary">
              <NotificationsIcon />
            </Badge>
          </IconButton>
          <Logout />
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        variant="permanent"
        classes={{
          paper: clsx(classes.drawerPaper, !open && classes.drawerPaperClose),
        }}
        open={open}
      >
        <div className={classes.toolbarIcon}>
          <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
            <ChevronLeftIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </div>
        <Divider />
        <SelectedListItem />
       
      </Drawer>
      <main className={classes.content}>
        <div className={classes.appBarSpacer} />

        //vvvvvvvvv here is the content I need to change vvvvvvvvvvv
        <Switch>

            <Route path="/Anfitrion" component={PropiedadesRegistradas}/>
            <Route exact path='/AgregarPropiedad' component={AgregarPropiedad} />
            <Route exact path= "/AreasRegistradas/:propertyId" component={AreasRegistradas}/>
            <Route exact path= "/ItemsAreasRegistradas/:propertyId" component={ItemsAreasRegistradas}/>            
            <Route exact path="/ElementosDeArea/:areaId" component = {ElementosDeArea} />
            <Route exact path="/AgregarItems/:areaId/:propertyId" component = {AgregarItems} />
            <Route exact path="/AgregarArea/:propertyId" component = {AgregarArea} />

            <Route exact path="/Supervisores" component={Supervisores}/>
            <Route exact path="/historial" component={Historial}/>
            <Route exact path="/Desinfeccion" component={Desinfeccion}/>
            <Route exact path="/Folios" component={Folios}/>    

            <Route exact path="/areasRegistradas" component={AreasRegistradas}/>
            <Route exact path= "/agregarSupervisor" component={AgregarSupervisor}/>
            <Route exact path="/detalle/:servicio/:hostId" component={Detalle} />
            <Route render={()=> <h3>Not found</h3>}/>

          </Switch>
          //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^here is the content I need to change^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      </main>
    </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

The problem is when I try to use the arrow buttons from the browser to go back and forward in the history, it displays a blank page. My guess is that it is due to the authentication process, because I can only go back or forward if the target page is "/Anfitrion".

What is the best way to do this so my users can go back and fwd?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you provide more code/context? It is difficult to analyze the issue with the details you currently have provided.

Comment: I just edited the question, I just didn't want to bore anyone with a lot of code. Thanks for the help!